# How to store a result in different files alphabetically

Tags: c, file, store

I m new to C.
I have a string of words for example a news paper article 
I want to store the words in the article to be stored in different files alphabetically
Like for example 'all around I see is inspiration, but I don't wanna be overwhelmed'.

Now in the above example I want to store all the words starting with `'a'` to be stored in a file `a.txt`. in the same way words starting with `'b'` to be stored in `b.txt`

I m using the syntax below but this is not working

```
{
    if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)
        fprintf(out_file1 ,"%c", wordcheck); //storing the value in a.txt            
}
```

I have another question, what if I take a text file which contains  a list of words and I want this list to be compared with a number of lists(already sourced to the program)means if any word in the input list matches with a word in any of the sourced list I want that word to be stored in file a.txt only if the word was found in list1.txt). similarly if the word is found in list2.txt I want it to be stored in b.txt. Along with that I want to display the path of the file list1.txt in the output file a.txt. 
Like 
sing ./dataset/dictionary/verb

I have used the syntax below

```
while(dictcount >= 0)//reads dictionary word into array//
{   
    dictcount = 0; //searches through all of the listed data files
    fscanf(fp1,"%s", worddict);
    fscanf(fp2,"%s", worddict);
    fscanf(fp3,"%s", worddict);
    if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)//compare strings//if the word in found in list misc.txt
    {
        fprintf(out_file1 ,"%c", wordcheck); //storing the value in output_misc.txt
        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
            //fprintf(out_file3, "%c\n", cwd); //stores the path of the folder containing the list in which the matched 'word' is found  
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` will compare the entire string, not just the parts you are interested in. So `'abcdef'` will not be equal to `'a'`, but if you used `strncmp()` and told it to only compare 1 byte would do what you want it to do.

But then, you're only comparing 1 byte so, why not just do this:

```
...
store_words(out_file, words, n_words, 'a');
...
void store_words(FILE *out_file, char *words, int n_words. char starter) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n_words; i++) {
        if(words[i][0] == starter) { // check if the first character is 'a' */
            fprintf(out_file ,words[i]); //if so storing the value in a.txt            
        }
    }
}
```

And then loop over all the characters in the alphabet? 
Note that C thinks 'a' and 'A' are different, but that can be fixed with a `tolower()`.

Comment: what if I use a text file which contains the text to be sorted

Comment: then you need to load it first, opening the file for writing will overwrite the contents.

Comment: I have another question. I have added it with my 1st question. can you please look?

Comment: So, now you'll overwrite worddict with your three reads, and I don't understand what getcwd() is supposed to accomplish?